# Importar, analisar e extrair dados de um CSV com PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Como posso fazer para importar um arquivo csv com PHP e pegar os dados de uma coluna específica e gravar esses dados no banco de dados? 
Tem como fazer essa análise e gravar só dados específicos (tipo uma coluna, ou linha)?

Comment: Sim é possível!

Comment: Boa... a questão é como? pode indicar uma referência? att

Comment: Pode começar com http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Answer (score 9):

Para realizar o processo de leitura de um arquivo csv no php é bem simples, visto que ele é entendido como um simples arquivo txt  que realiza sua separação utilizando o `;`, então você poderia utilizar funções como fopen para poder abrir ele, percorrer e salvar em uma variavel.

**Exemplo Leitura:**

```
function getCSV($name) {
   $file = fopen($name, "r");
   $result = array();
   $i = 0;
   while (!feof($file)):
      if (substr(($result[$i] = fgets($file)), 0, 10) !== ';;;;;;;;') :
         $i++;
      endif;
   endwhile;
   fclose($file);
   return $result;
}

$foo = getCSV('foo.csv');
```

Leitura normal certo ? apenas acrescentei um detalhe, aquele if dentro do loop é pra previnir um bugzinho que acontece em algumas versões do excel, este e, quando você realiza um scroll nas colunas, estas colunas em branco recebem o ;;;;;; sem exatamente ter um valor. ai no final você acaba salvando um array com "lixos".

Agora que você tem um array com tudo! você pode pegar linha a linha realizando um simples explode.

**Exemplo Leitura linha a linha:**

```
function getLine($array, $index) {
   return explode(';', $array[$index]);
}

var_dump(getLine($foo, 0));
```

Então se eu tiver uma planilha assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Chamando a funçao terei um array assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E para ler campo a campo desta linha você pode salvar em uma variavel e acessar o índice especifico:

```
$bar = getLine($foo, 0);
var_dump($bar[0]);
```

Neste caso pegando a primeira coluna, você pode automatizar realizando um loop para percorrer gravando campo a campo.

**Um exemplo de inserção genérico poderia ser:**

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
mysqli_query($con, 'INSERT INTO Persons (foo,bar) VALUES (' . $bar[0] . ',' . $bar[1] . ')');
mysqli_close($con);
```

Existe também a possibilidade de ler este arquivo no javascript. se você quiser fazer uma validação inicial de algum campo antes de realizar upload para sua base e realmente começar a importação, isto pode gerar muita economia de desempenho do servidor e alto feedback ao usuario.

Tem uma solução utilizando FileReader.

**Exemplo:**

```js
var leitorDeCSV = new FileReader();

window.onload = function init() {
  leitorDeCSV.onload = leCSV;
}

function pegaCSV(inputFile) {
  var file = inputFile.files[0];
  leitorDeCSV.readAsText(file);
}

function leCSV(evt) {

  var fileArr = evt.target.result.split('\n');
  var strDiv = '<table>';

  for (var i = 0; i < fileArr.length; i++) {
    strDiv += '<tr>';
    var fileLine = fileArr[i].split(',');
    for (var j = 0; j < fileLine.length; j++) {
      strDiv += '<td>' + fileLine[j].trim() + '</td>';
    }
    strDiv += '</tr>';
  }

  strDiv += '</table>';

  var CSVsaida = document.getElementById('CSVsaida');
  CSVsaida.innerHTML = strDiv;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="inputCSV" onchange="pegaCSV(this)">
<div id="CSVsaida"></div>
```