# Como passar dados do excel para MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, microsoft-excel

Primeiro, tenho um sistema newsletter que modifiquei para email marketing, ele é todo em PHP (óbvio) e primeiramente, eu adiciono os emails manualmente por uma parte do site *add.php* mas há mais de 3000 emails a serem adicionados e vai demorar muito para fazer isso manualmente.

Enfim a pergunta é:

**Teria algum modo de passar uma lista de email do excel para o banco de dados no MYSQL ?**

*uso o phpmyadmin* não sei se ajuda a especificar...

Caso não entendam podem comentar que tento explicar melhor.

Comment: Sim é possível, acredite! qual é a estrutura do excel? é possível converter para um csv?

Comment: ótimo saber disso amigo, já esta em csv, fica mais fácil?

Comment: Veja [isso](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/118629/91) para extrair os valores do csv, depois é so formatar a SQL e inserir.

Comment: desculpe sou leigo no assunto, como assim "formatar a sql" ?

Comment: Montar o `INSERT INTO tabela(campo) VALUES('email@teste.com')`

Comment: Ou pode usar o phpmyadmin veja [essa respostas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23654356/1342547)

Comment: Cara muito obrigado, resolveu meu problema por completo, me economizou horas e horas hahaha

Answer (score 10):

Salva essa lista como csv e importa através do phpmyadmin ou do HeidiSQL.

**phpmyadmin:**

1 - No excel, salve a planilha como csv

2 - Abra o phpmyadmin e selecione a tabela onde você queria inserir os dados

3 - selecione a aba importar

4 - Carregue o arquivo csv, altere a codificação para ISO-8859-1 o formato deverá ser CSV e opção "Columns separated with:" deve ser preenchida como ";"

[image: PHP]

**HeidoSQL:**

1 - No excel, salve a planilha como csv

2 - Abra o phpmyadmin e selecione a tabela onde você queria inserir os dados

3 - Vá em Ferramentas->Importar arquivo CSV

4 - Na janela que se abriu selecione o arquivo e codificação e clique em importar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Explique melhor o procedimento

Comment: Desculpe minha displicência Marlon

Comment: Muito bom Rafael, gostei, não sabia que dava pra fazer isso diretamente pelo phpmyadmin, mesmo já estando resolvido meu problema, agradeço a explicação, vai ser útil para novas pessoas que também estiverem com o mesmo problema.

Comment: Obrigado Victor, Sim, esse método já me ajudou bastante, espero que ajude a galera.

Comment: No caso do phpMyAdmin, tenho que ter uma tabela no excel igualzinha a tabela no banco de dados ou posso importar somente uma coluna da tabela, por exemplo?

Comment: Resolveu meu problema, obrigada.

Comment: @MarianaFerreira Mariana, neste caso as colunas do seu csv tem que ser na mesma ordem e na mesma quantidade que a tabela de destino. Através do Heidi é possível ignorar algumas colunas. Esse dois métodos são uma interface amigável para o comando LOAD DATA INFILE, se você precisar corrigir alguns dados ou ignorar algumas colunas procure mais sobre essa função que você poderá rodar diretamente. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html