# Problemas ao exportar do PHP para CSV

Tags: php

Estou com problema na hora de visualizar um arquivo csv. A minha intenção é que possa usar o comando do Excel "dados para coluna" e fique linha a linha, mas o arquivo tem pulado linha impossibilitando. O código foi feito baseado em um outro exemplo aqui mesmo postado por um adm.

```
     date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

ini_set('memory_limit', '12000M');
 require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/administrator/lib/connection.php");

//echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> window.open(\"http://www.tometoo.com.br/generateCSV2.php\", \"_blank\")</script>";

        $PDO = Database::Connect();

        $SQL = "SELECT idpost, idcomment, cm_id_author, pg_name, ps_date, cm_date, ps_message, cm_name_author, cm_message, pss_likes, pss_shares, pss_comments, cms_like, cms_reply 
        from fb_post
        INNER JOIN fb_pssummary ON pss_idpost = idpost
        INNER JOIN fb_page ON ps_idpage = idpage
        INNER JOIN fb_comment ON cm_idpost = idpost
        INNER JOIN fb_cmsummary ON cms_idcomment = idcomment 
        where ps_date between '2016-09-01 00:00' and '2016-09-01 23:59:59'
        ORDER BY ps_date ASC";
        
        $SQL = $PDO->prepare($SQL);

        $SQL->execute();

        $result = $SQL->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


        function array_para_csv(array &$array)
        {
           if (count($array) == 0) {
             return null;
           }
           ob_start();
           $df = fopen("php://output", 'w');
           fputcsv($df, array_keys(reset($array)));
           foreach ($array as $row) {
              fputcsv($df, $row);
           }
           fclose($df);
           return ob_get_clean();
        }

        function cabecalho_download_csv($filename) {
    // desabilitar cache
    $now = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s");
    header("Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate");
    header("Last-Modified: {$now} GMT");

    // forçar download  
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");

    // disposição do texto / codificação
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename={$filename}");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
}


cabecalho_download_csv("setembro_1_1M_1_parte" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
echo array_para_csv($result);
```

a saída tem ficado assim no excel
229151370439618_1206843959337016,1206843959337016_1206850609336351,1063115217101837,CartaCapital,"2016-09-01 00:15:31","2016-09-01 00:27:42","VIOLÃŠNCIA POLICIAL
O centro de SÃ£o Paulo se tornou uma verdadeira praÃ§a de guerra hoje a noite, a partir do momento que PolÃ­cia Militar, resolveu dispersar a manifestaÃ§Ã£o contra o golpe a partir do meio dela. O efeito, foi a dispersÃ£o de manifestantes para diversos cantos e uma verdadeira caÃ§a  promovida pelos policiais a base de bombas e balas de borracha.
Segundo informaÃ§Ãµes, uma jovem estÃ¡ neste momento no Hospital da ClÃ­nicas com a forte possibilidade de ter perdido a visÃ£o de um olho e um fotÃ³grafo teve seu equipamento de trabalho quebrado e foi detido.
AtÃ© o momento, nem mesmos os advogados do fotÃ³grafo foram informados sobre o motivo da detenÃ§Ã£o
Imagens por Tadeu Amaral

## Golpe #Impeachment","Marco Antonio Camelo","Carta capital defende bandidos.",418,76,263,4,0

favor ignorar o conteúdo do facebook que não tem nada a ver com minha opinião. Como podem observar além da acentuação tem o problema das linhas.

Comment: Qual o fator de separação usado no arquivo `.csv`? Eu uso o ponto-e-vúrgula.

Comment: Essa é uma das partes da minha dúvida, como poderia colocar o delimitador , mas o estranho é ele pular linha, não criar uma única linha por retorno do while.

Comment: foi colocado um `\r\n` no fim de cada linha, mas, se não souber o fator de separação, não saberá como dividir corretamente o texto.

Comment: não coloquei o \r\n nem PHP_EOL pois essa função do PHP parece fazer isso, o delimitador que ta usando é a vírgula

Comment: Os separadores, quando tem texto, mais recomendados são ponto-e-vírgula e pipe. Sem contar que se está escolhendo a forma certa de abertura na própria planilha.

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse post, eu respondo como ler/gravar  e visualizar o csv http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/118619/importar-analisar-e-extrair-dados-de-um-csv-com-php/118629#118629

Comment: Olha, eu usei essa classe uma vez para criar um arquivo em excel https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel com base nesse exemplo : http://www.voltsdigital.com.br/labs/gerando-planilhas-excel-com-php/

Comment: Use a [biblioteca PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/).  E pare de sofrer.

Comment: Obrigado a todos, e vou parar de sofrer! hahaha Aplicando a biblioteca aqui no projeto.

Answer (score 3):

Uma solução para evitar este tipo de problema é através de uma biblioteca muito bem desenvolvida [PHP Excel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel):

1) Após baixar a biblioteca [PHP Excel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)

2) Basta utilizá-la da seguinte maneira a partir do seu código:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1); //mostra todos os erros (-1 ou E_ALL)
ini_set('memory_limit', '12000M');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/administrator/lib/connection.php");
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/administrator/lib/PHPEXcel/Writer/PHPExcel.php");
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/administrator/lib/PHPEXcel/Writer/Excel2007.php");

$PDO = Database::Connect();

$SQL = "SELECT idpost, idcomment, cm_id_author, pg_name, ps_date, cm_date, ps_message, cm_name_author, cm_message, pss_likes, pss_shares, pss_comments, cms_like, cms_reply 
        from fb_post
        INNER JOIN fb_pssummary ON pss_idpost = idpost
        INNER JOIN fb_page ON ps_idpage = idpage
        INNER JOIN fb_comment ON cm_idpost = idpost
        INNER JOIN fb_cmsummary ON cms_idcomment = idcomment 
        where ps_date between :initial and :final
        ORDER BY ps_date ASC";

$SQL = $PDO->prepare($SQL);
$SQL->execute([':initial'=>'2016-09-01 00:00', ':final'=>'2016-09-01 23:59:59']);

$result = $SQL->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

exportExcel("nome_do_arquivo", $result);

function exportExcel($filename, $result)
{ 
    $result = addHeader($result);
    $export = new PHPExcel();
    $cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_phpTemp;
    $cacheSettings = array(' memoryCacheSize ' => '8MB');
    PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings);

    $export->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->fromArray($result, null, 'A1');

    $xmlWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($export);

    header("Pragma: protected"); // required
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: public", false); // required for certain browsers
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='{$filename}.xlsx'");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    $xmlWriter->save("php://output");
    exit();
}

function addHeader($value)
{
    $return = null;
    if (is_array($value)) {
        $header = array_keys($value[0]);
        $return[0] = $header;
        foreach ($value as $key => $row) {
            foreach ($row as $columnKey => $column) {
                $currentfindedKey = array_search($columnKey, $header);
                $return[$key][$currentfindedKey] = $column;
            }
        }
        array_unshift($return, $header);
    }
   return $return;
}
```

Comment: Valeu mesmo!!!! Vou fazer o teste aqui agora.

Comment: Olá Ivan, fiz os testes aqui e constatei que uso essa lib em meu template. O problema que encontro nela é em gerar um quantidade grande de linhas. No meu caso, como atuo com big data, preciso gerar alguns CSV`s que chegam a 20gb, algo perto de 8M de linhas. Com essa lib eu gero até umas 20 mil linhas sem problemas, após isso, fica muito tempo de processamento, mesmo em segundo plano leva em torno de 2 horas pra começar o download, o que inviabiliza o relatório, no CSV ao menos o download é imediato. Se lembrar de algo que possa compartilhar, fico grato!!! Abs

Comment: Mas conseguiu o que desejava?

Comment: @IvanFerrer seu link foi trocado do Codeplex pro GitHub pois o primeiro está sendo desativado. Está sendo feito um esforço conjunto pela mudança: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6317/codeplex-ser%C3%A1-desativado-no-dia-25-12-2017-que-tal-atualizarmos-os-links?cb=1. Caso o link que usei foi inapropriado, favor escolher um que o seja mas que não venha do Codeplex. Grata.

Comment: @IvanFerrer reverti para a edição da Carla, o Codeplex, como explicado no link citado, esta sendo descontinuado.